# Pass handle down pipeline

Tags: node.js, macos, stdin, pid, file-descriptor

Say I have

```
node foo.js | node bar.js
```

is there a way to pass a handle on foo's stdin to bar.js?

I have a rare case where I'd like to communicate backwards in the pipeline.

At the least I know that I could send `node bar.js` the pid of `node foo.js`. Given that pid, on *nix, I should be able to write to foo's stdin using:

```
/proc/<pid>/fd/0
```

but is there a way to do the same on MacOS?

Comment: If you need bidirectional communication, it may be better to use a socket (TCP or Unix).  Would such a solution be acceptable?

Comment: @cdhowie yes that would be great, x-platform preferable if possible

Comment: @AlexanderMills, did you get a chance to look at my answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So there are different ways of doing it.

**Approach 1 - IOCTL**

This is inspired from

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36522620/2830850

So you create `writevt.c` file with below content

```
/*
 * Mostly ripped off of console-tools' writevt.c
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char *progname;

static int usage() {
    printf("Usage: %s ttydev text\n", progname);
    return 2;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int fd, argi;
    char *term = NULL;
    char *text = NULL;

    progname = argv[0];

    argi = 1;

    if (argi < argc)
        term = argv[argi++];
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: no tty specified\n", progname);
        return usage();
    }

    if (argi < argc)
        text = argv[argi++];
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: no text specified\n", progname);
        return usage();
    }

    if (argi != argc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: too many arguments\n", progname);
        return usage();
    }

    fd = open(term, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror(term);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: could not open tty\n", progname);
        return 1;
    }

    while (*text) {
        if (ioctl(fd, TIOCSTI, text)) {
            perror("ioctl");
            return 1;
        }
        text++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compile it using below

```
gcc -o writevt writevt.c
```

Then add `root` permission to the same

```
sudo chown root:wheel writevt
sudo chmod 4755 writevt
```

Now I created a simple `foo.js` with below code

```
var stdin = process.openStdin();

stdin.addListener("data", function(d) {
    console.log(process.env.NAME + " entered: [" +
        d.toString().trim() + "]");
});
```

And in a terminal run first the `tty` command

```
$ tty
/dev/ttys019
```

And now run the code like below

```
NAME=A node foo.js  | NAME=B node foo.js
```

Now from another terminal run the below command

```
./writevt /dev/ttys019 "FROM external command^M"
```

`^M` here is `CTRL+V` + `CTRL+ENTER` on Mac

[image: Content]

As you can see from the `gif` the input reaches `stdin` of A and then A prints on stdout and which is received by B then. So if I modify the code like below

```
var stdin = process.openStdin();

stdin.addListener("data", function(d) {
    console.log(process.env.NAME + " entered: [" +
        d.toString().trim() + "]");
});

if (process.env.NAME === "B") {
    setInterval(function() {
        require('child_process').exec(`./writevt /dev/ttys019 "Hello from B?
"`)
    }, 1000)
}
```

**Note 1**: `^M` was added using Vim inside the above code

**Note 2**: The TTY location has been hard coded in this but you can pass it through a environment variable by running

```
export TTY=`tty`
```

And then using `process.env.TTY` in the code. The updated results are

[image: Working]

**Approach 2 - FIFO files**

In this approach you make a fifo file first

```
$ mkfifo nodebridge
```

Now you change your code like below

```
var stdin = process.openStdin();
var fs = require("fs")
stdin.addListener("data", function(d) {
    console.log(process.env.NAME + " entered: [" +
        d.toString().trim() + "]");
});

if (process.env.NAME === "B") {
    setInterval( () => {
        require('child_process').exec('printf "Hello from B?\\n" > nodebridge')
    }, 1000);
}
```

And run the command like below

```
NAME=A node foo.js < nodebridge | NAME=B node foo.js
```

[image: NodeBridge]

Comment: Good explanation, how do you create gif? What program? :)

Comment: @MaciejPulikowski, I got a better alternative from someone else on SO. Now i use https://getkap.co/

Comment: If you use Linux, then a good choice is https://github.com/phw/peek. Now don't say I used windows ;)